# Redis cache write return false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, redis, sidekiq

After upgrading the redis version in order to upgrade to sidekiq version 7. Whenever I try to write to the cache it returns false. But sidekiq works correctly.

Sidekiq 7.0.0
redis gem 5.0.5
redis 7.0.5

```
3.1.1 :003 > Rails.cache
 => #<ActiveSupport::Cache::RedisCacheStore options={:namespace=>nil, :compress=>true, :compress_threshold=>1024, :expires_in=>nil, :race_condition_ttl=>nil} redis=#<Redis client v5.0.5 for redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0>> 

3.1.1 :005 > Rails.cache.write 'test', 'test'
 => false
```

EDIT:

Solved.The problem was in the new redis.conf file that was generated when upgrading.

Comment: Have you enabled your cache in development ? `rails dev:cache`

Comment: Yes, all this is testing in a production environment.

Comment: I have this exact same problem. Can you give any clues about how to check & fix the redis.conf file?

Comment: I don't think I have modified anything except ports. What I did do to make it work for me was to go back to the previous conf I had before the upgrade.